# D3: Text to a bar chart doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newbie with d3.js and I'm trying to create a bar chart graphic but after  creating the first two bars when I try to create the third the text what I want to add to the bar is hidden behind the bar.

Here is my code:

```
   const kHeightSVG1 = 241;
    const xMargin = 30;
    const yTopMargin = 15;
    const yBottomMargin = 50;
    const barWidth = 50;
    const localAdvStats = this.state.local_tcas["data"]["team_tcas"][0];
    const awayAdvStats =  this.state.away_tcas["data"]["team_tcas"][0];
    const abrevLocalTeam = this.state.local_team["data"]["teamclub"][0]["abrev"];
    const abrevAwayTeam = this.state.away_team["data"]["teamclub"][0]["abrev"];
    let svg1 = d3.select("#graph1").style("background-color", "#091E36");
    svg1.attr("height", kHeightSVG1);
    svg1.attr("width", "100%");
    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([kHeightSVG1-yBottomMargin-yTopMargin, 0]);
    //Añadimos eje de las y
    let g = svg1.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + xMargin + "," + yTopMargin + ")");
    g.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d){
        return d;
    }).ticks(10)).style("color", "#FFFFFF");
    //Bar1
    //Añadimos primer bloque de etc
    console.log("yScale: " + yScale(localAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin);
    let g1 = svg1.append("g");
    g1.append("rect")
    .attr("x", xMargin+3)
    .attr("y", yScale(localAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin)
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", kHeightSVG1-yTopMargin-yBottomMargin-yScale(localAdvStats["etc"]));
    // //Añadimos cifra a la primera barra
    g1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xMargin + "," + yTopMargin + ")")
    .attr("x", xMargin+10)
    .attr("y", yScale(localAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin)
    .attr("font-size", "32px")
    .text(localAdvStats["etc"]);
    g1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xMargin + "," + yTopMargin + ")")
    .attr("x", xMargin+12)
    .attr("y", yScale(localAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin + 12)
    .text("(" + abrevLocalTeam + ")");
    //Bar 2
    let g2 = svg1.append("g");
    g2.append("rect")
    .attr("x", barWidth + xMargin + 3)
    .attr("y", yScale(awayAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin)
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", kHeightSVG1-yTopMargin-yBottomMargin-yScale(awayAdvStats["etc"]));
    g2.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth*2.5)
    .attr("y", yScale(awayAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin + 12)
    .attr("font-size", "32px")
    .text(awayAdvStats["etc"]);
    g2.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth*2.5)
    .attr("y", yScale(awayAdvStats["etc"]) + yTopMargin + 24)
    .text("(" + abrevAwayTeam + ")");
    //Bar 3
    let g3 = svg1.append("g");
    g3.append("rect")
    .attr("x", barWidth*3 + xMargin)
    .attr("y", yScale(localAdvStats["p_reb_of"]) + yTopMargin)
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", kHeightSVG1-yTopMargin-yBottomMargin-yScale(localAdvStats["p_reb_of"]));
    g3.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth*3 + xMargin + 10)
    .attr("y", yScale(localAdvStats["p_ref_of"]) + yTopMargin)
    .attr("font-size", "32px")
    .text(localAdvStats["p_reb_of"]);
```

What I've got with this code is two bars with the text over them but a third with the text behind it.

[image]

Bar 2 and Bar 3 are made it equals but Bar 3 doesn't appear text over bar chart. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using d3 the wrong way -- you shouldn't be creating each bar individually. Instead you should only describe how to calculate bars properties from a data element, and have d3 data binding deal with the creation itself. Have a look at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Comment: Hi!!! But I would like to mix several sources of data with different data in the same graphic. I can do it with the first two bars but I don't know what happend with the third bar when I try to do the same with other data. Thanks in advance for your help